# How can i use two models in same controller(EntityFramwork) and use each in different action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have made one model so far and added controller using EF, and made some list of books

```
public class Books
    {
        public string ImageUr { get; set; }
        public string BookTitle { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class BooksDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Books> Book { get; set; }
    }
```

and im displaying that list in this action:

```
 public ActionResult Books()
        {
            return View(db.Book.ToList());
        }
```

and my question is how can i make another model or database that will be passed into this action (viewpage for news about new books for example):

```
public ActionResult News()
        {
             View(db.News.ToList());
        }
```

and the model for news to be something like this:

```
public class News
        {
            public string Title{ get; set; }
            public string Subtitle { get; set; }
            public string Content{ get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well maybe you can try out a viewmodel. When I started learning ASP.NET MVC I did the tutorial Working with data and learned a lot about entity framework and ASP.NET MVC! I will give you a link. [ASP.NET working with data](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

For your solution some code:

**UPDATE** You will need some virtual properties in your classes to define the relationships: we have a one to many relationship because book can have more news items and news can only have one book.

```
public class Book //change your class name to book 
{
    public string ImageUr { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; } 
}

public class News
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Content{ get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public int BookId {get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
 }
```

**if your want to use a viewmodel then add a new folder named viewmodels and add a new class**

```
public class BookNewsViewmodel //viewmodel of book and News :)
{
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext

```
namespace yourProject.DAL
{
    public class yourProjectContext : DbContext //this is a DbContext!
    {

        public yourProjectContext () : base("yourProjectContext") //A constructor
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; } //make a DbSet of your classes
        public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Pluralize your tablenames from Books to Book and from Newss to News :)
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller:

**With viewmodel**

```
public ActionResult BookNewsIndex()
{
    var viewModel = new BookNewsViewmodel();
    viewModel.Books = db.Books
    .Include(n => n.News)



    return View(viewModel.ToList()); //return your data.ToList() to your view
}
```

**Without a viewmodel**

```
public ActionResult BookNewsIndex()
{
    var data = db.Books.Include(n => n.News); 


    return View(data.ToList()); //return your data.ToList() to your view
}
```

In your View named BookNewsIndex you can do this. I am not sure about this but you can give it a try

```
@model yourproject.ViewModels.BookNewsViewmodel for your viewmodel
OR
@model IEnumerable<yourProject.Models.Book> without viewmodel

with viewmodel
@model.Books.ShortDescription 
@model.News.Subtitle

without viewmodel
@Model.First().ShortDescription get something from your book! 
@Model.First().News.First().Subtitle get something from news!
```

[In part 7 of the tutorial he will use a viewmodel](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you very much, ill check the links now.

Comment: I will add the DbContext for you @CodeCaster has a point on that! :)

Comment: This example looks like you are combining them into one view, which i dont need :( i need each in different view... or am i missing something?

Comment: In that case I will update my answer one moment please

Comment: Tobias, thank you for your help, i found another solution that works for newbies like me :D

Comment: Oke what was your solution? I am curious! :D If you solved your own solution post it as a answer! This is handy for those that have the same problem as you! :)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with MVC, but with Entity Framework.

You'll have to add the `DbSet` for `News`:

```
public class BooksDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Books> Book { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, can you be more specific, does it need to have a databes table for News items, or if its not too much to ask can you provide a link with similar problem like mine or anything that can help me about this.

Comment: I don't see how I can be more specific. :) All you need is in my answer. What don't you understand?

Comment: Well im kinda new in this so thats the problem ;( so after putting dbset for news, im not sure how to proceed, do i have to add a database for news so i can create some news items, and lastly to return view in action, because im getting error now for --  public ActionResult News()
        {
             View(db.News.ToList());
        }